# Wi-Fi stops working until disconnected and reconnected

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have a desktop running Windows 10 and the Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 7265 card. The drivers for the wireless card are fully updated.

My problem is, after using being connected to the Wi-Fi for anywhere from a few seconds to a few hours, it stops working and doesn't start working again unless you wait around 5-10 minutes, or you disconnect and reconnect to the network, where it starts working again instantly. It is extremely annoying to have to disconnect and reconnect from the network, especially if it stops working just a few seconds later. It occurs with every Wi-Fi network I've tried (I took it to a friends house once and it had the same issues).

I have run Windows Network Diagnostics when it acts up and it resets the Wi-Fi adapter (which fixes the problem as well temporarily) or finds nothing.

Does anyone know the cause of this? As I've said, the drivers are fully updated, and I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers as well as adjusting the antenna positioning on the case, and neither have solved the issue.

Comment: Next time it happens run Windows Network Diagnostics.

Comment: Oh yeah, I've done that multiple times, and it either resets the Wi-Fi adapter (which fixes the problem as well temporarily) or finds nothing. I can't tell how it picks which one to do

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it sounds like your Wlan card is failing. As you can replicate the problem on another network.(ruling out your wireless access point as the potential problem.)  It's possibly overheating the chipset with the description in your question.

You can try making a live boot USB stick of Ubuntu 18+ or similar to rule out a Windows problem with the drivers. Luckily the adapter is cheap, ($13~$20 U.S) on eBay.

Most modern computers including most full sized laptops have easily accessible mini PCI-e slots for replacement.

If you want to add the actual computer make/model to the question I would be happy to update this answer with **instructions for your computer** to replace it.

~Regards